# WP_Query search by meta_key value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a meta field "a" with a1, a2, a11 multiplie values, etc.

**get_post_meta(id, 'a'); displayed: Array array ([0] => a1 [1] => a6)**

I do search by this code

```
array(
'key' => 'a',
'value' => 'a1',
'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
```

But there was a problem, LIKE does not exact search and coincidence. at a1 value records with the field a11 are also displayed. How it is possible to correct it that search was precisely on a1 to value?

```
'value' => 'a1',
'compare' => '='
```

And

```
'value' => array('a1'),
'compare' => 'IN'
```

don't work. nothing is displayed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP\_Query search by meta\_key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674948/wp-query-search-by-meta-key)

Answer (score 1):

i think this code woring.

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
        'meta_key'   => 'age',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'age',
                'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Use custom query via `get_results`.

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'a' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'a1' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";
 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Comment: how to transform this code in custom query?

    `$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => '_price',
    'orderby' => $ordrby,
    'order' => $order_date,
    'product_cat' => $category_ID,
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key' => 'a',
    'value' => $value_a,
    'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
    'key' => '_price',
    'value' => array($price1, $price2),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    )
    );
    }`

Comment: and i can use this in wp_pagenavi args? now i use 

`$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $loop ));`

Comment: yes, but then it displays all posts. because this field exists everywhere

Comment: **Array array ([0] => a1 [1] => a6)**. 

values are filled with a plugin "advanced custom fields pro". input type - multiplie select.